# Question about Real analysis: Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R} ) $ be the sigma algebra generates by the family of  open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to understand this concept. According to the definition, if we call $\mathcal{O} $ the collection of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, then

$$ \sigma(\mathcal{O}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R} ) = \bigcap \{ \mathcal{F} : \mathcal{F} \; \text{is a sigma algebra and} \; \; \mathcal{O} \subset \mathcal{F} \}$$

Since any element in $\mathcal{O}$ is a union of open intervals $(a,b)$, can I say that the elements of $\mathcal{ B}( R) $ are just intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. Sigma algebras are quite complicated objects if one tries to understand them 'too much'. Since countable unions of sets in a sigma algebra are again in the sigma algebra, we also have something like:

$$A_n := \left( \frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), n\geq 2 \Rightarrow [0,1] = \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$

Hence, also closed intervals are in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

A tutor once told us to imagine the following:

1. Take all open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Add all sets that can be written as countable unions of the already obtained sets.
3. Add all sets that can be written as countable intersections of the already obtained sets.

Now repeat steps 2. and 3. over and over and over and over.....

Each step produces some new sets, which shows that sigma algebras are in general quite complicated.

Answer (score 2):

A union of 2 intervals is not an interval.